# Get option values from muti selection when closest button clicked

Tags: jquery, select, element, closest

I have a form with several multi-select elements each with their own add and remove buttons. How do I associate the closest select element with each of the add and remove buttons.

Here is one small section of the HTML:

```
<div>Administrator</div>
<input type="button" class="add" value="Add" /> | <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" />

<select name="list_1" size="10" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">John Doe</option>
    <option value="3">Jimmy Jack</option>
    <option value="13">George Stephen</option>
    <option value="26">Joe Smith</option>
    <option value="30">Mary Kay</option>
    <option value="76">Ace Ventura</option>
</select>
```

Here's the jQuery I've tried so far. All of the values returned are undefined:

```
$('.remove').click( function( e ) {     

    var temp1 = $(this).prev('select').val();
    var temp2 = $(this).next('select').val();
    var temp3 = $(this).closest('select').val();        
    var temp4 = $(e.target).prev('select').val();
    var temp5 = $(e.target).next('select').val();
    var temp6 = $(e.target).closest('select').val();

    window.console&&console.log('temp1: ' + temp1); 
    window.console&&console.log('temp2: ' + temp2); 
    window.console&&console.log('temp3: ' + temp3); 
    window.console&&console.log('temp4: ' + temp4); 
    window.console&&console.log('temp5: ' + temp5); 
    window.console&&console.log('temp6: ' + temp6); 

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Why don't you assign an id to the select, and call it?

Comment: I have nearly 100 selection elements. I want to make it as generic as possible. Unless you know a better way, but I don't want to access individual IDs.

Comment: A better way is to use a class :)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, but I'm always open for suggestions and looking for ways to improve my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check your original code again.
I've just copied your code and $().next works just fine.

```
var temp2 = $(this).next('select').val();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM74N/1/)

Comment: You got me here. Indeed it does work via fiddle, but I still cannot get it to show values on my form...weird.

Comment: On my local copy I had the Add / Remove buttons wrapped in the same div as Administrator. I changed that to match what I posted here and it works! This is why I keep my hair short. Thanks Prosto.

Comment: well, then you could use .parent().next('select')